# Will my objects be garbage collected?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

This is the data provider:

```
class Item {
  private String text;
  public Item(String txt) {
    this.text = txt;
  }
  public String get() {
    return this.text;
  }
  public static Item next() {
    return new Item("hello");
  }
}
```

Now I'm trying to do this (just an example, to understand how it works):

```
List<String> texts = new LinkedList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
  Item item = Item.next();
  texts.add(item.get());
}
// do we still have ten thousand Items in memory,
// or they should already be garbage collected?
```

I wonder whether GC will destroy all `Item` objects, or they will stay in memory since my `List` holds 10000 links to their parts (`text`)?

Comment: It will only clean up objects which are not strongly unreachable.  What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: My actual problem is Memory leak when working with MongoDB (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18684598/memory-leak-in-mongodb-cursor-outofmemory), but here I'm trying to confirm that it's not my code that is leaking

Comment: The only difference between your code and the simple case of adding the strings directly to the list is that you needlessly slaughter 10,000 cute little objects.

Comment: Of course, short of a bug in the JDK (or in JNI code), a "memory leak" is impossible in Java.  But it's fairly common to "forget" objects -- eg, create a long list, replace it, but forget that it's also referenced from somewhere else (perhaps from an object in the new list).  There are some tools that can help diagnose this.

Comment: If you want to find the memory leak you should use a memory profiler or analyse a heap dump. The JDK comes with a free one as does many IDes. Its much better than guessing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you're not keeping references to the `Item` objects, just to the strings, the `Item` objects are eligible for GC. The strings are not, as they are referenced.

After the first iteration of your loop, you have this:

```
+------+
| item |
+------+
| text |----+
+------+    |   +---------+
            +-> | "Hello" |
            |   +---------+
+-------+   |
| texts |   |
+-------+   |
| 0     |---+
+-------+
```

So both `item` and `texts` point to the string, but nothing points back to `item`, so that `Item` can be GC'd.

---

*Slightly* off-topic:

Your example as shown will have only one `String` instance which is referenced 10,000 times in the list, because it's a string literal, and string literals are `intern`'d automatically. But the answer wouldn't change if it were a different string in each case. The strings are separate from the `Item`s.